# Rejecting IAP - iTunes Connect

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I ran a test submission on my app using iTunes Connect, and I accidentally selected all of my IAP to be submitted as well. The submission didn't go through, but the IAP remained "Waiting For Review". There is no way to reject the IAP or deselect the IAP for submission at this point (the option goes away once the app goes "Waiting For Upload" for the first time).

Does anyone know how to get the IAP rejected? Rejecting the app didn't release the IAP (I had read that that would work, but it didn't). Not all of the IAP I selected will be in this version, so Apple will surely reject my app when it finds the submitted IAP is not there.

Anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can contact the App Review team which can reject that IAP for you. https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/7.0.0.7.5.0.0.11.0.0.5.1